# Rsync a un rango de ips

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto y me surgido la duda, si tengo una red y de está cuelgan varias subredes, hay alguna manera de especificar a rsync que haga las copias a un rango de ip's? Es posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un bucle y un array.

Algo parecido a esto

```
array=( "ip1", "ip2", "ip3" )

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    scp -i /llave/privada.pem /archivo/que/deseamos/copiar \
    user@$i:/ruta/donde/queremos/copiar/el/archivo
done
```

Esto suponiendo que ingresas por medio de llaves y todos los servidores tienen el mismo usuario y misma llave.